# scope singleton in one bean and prototype other dependent bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I need to understand how Spring will behave on the below situation. Suppose I have two beans in my application-context.xml

**Case 1:**

```
<bean id="user" class="com.test.User" >
    <constructor-arg ref="department"/>
</bean>
<bean id="department" class="com.test.Department" scope="protoType"></bean>
```

**Case 2:**

```
<bean id="user" class="com.test.User" scope="protoType">
    <constructor-arg ref="department"/>
</bean>

<bean id="department" class="com.test.Department"></bean>
```

Comment: Case 1 everything will be a singleton, Case 2, all new users will share the department.

Comment: @M.Deinum, would you kindly audit my answer? I guess you solution to case1 is not correct

Comment: From the scope of the User there is only 1 department, if you start accessing the bean factory and request for department instances yourself you will get new ones, but that isn't clear from the question. So from the user perspective and if you don't request new instance everything is basically a singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First case:**

`User` bean will be singleton. At the time of context creation it will get a new instance of the `Department` bean. Every time the `Department` bean is injected / accessed from  application context a new instance of `Department` will be created. It won't be the same as the one previously injected into `User` bean.

**Second case:**

Every time the `User` bean will be injected / requested from the context it will be a newly created bean with the reference to the singleton `Department` bean.